# How to change defualt graphic card to NVIDIA graphic card?

Tags: 16.04, graphics

My system info is

[image]

And my machine has a NVIDIA GTX 660 graphic card, How do I change defualt graphic card to NVIDIA graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

To use your GPU, all you have to do is install the drivers and reboot, run these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-370
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting, you will be using your Nvidia card.